# Why does my AI rotate on the y axis?

Tags: unity, 2d

I have a simple sensing script to sense when my player is close to the enemy but when my player gets close to the enemy, it turns -90° on the y axis.

Here is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAlert: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float idleDistance = 10f;
    public float walkDistance = 5f;
    public float runDistance = 3f;


    public float walkSpeed = 2f;
    public float runSpeed = 5f;
    public float attackDelay = 1f;
    
    private Animator anim;
    private bool isAttacking = false;

    private enum EnemyState
    {
        Idle,
        Walking,
        Running,
        Attacking
    }

    private EnemyState currentState;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        currentState = EnemyState.Idle;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        switch (currentState)
        {
            case EnemyState.Idle:
                if (distanceToPlayer <= idleDistance)
                {
                    currentState = EnemyState.Walking;
                }
                break;
            case EnemyState.Walking:
                if (distanceToPlayer <= runDistance)
                {
                    currentState = EnemyState.Running;
                }
                else if (distanceToPlayer > walkDistance)
                {
                    currentState = EnemyState.Idle;
                }
                else
                {
                    transform.LookAt(new Vector3(player.position.x, transform.position.y, player.position.z));
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                break;
            case EnemyState.Running:
                if (distanceToPlayer > runDistance)
                {
                    currentState = EnemyState.Walking;
                }
                else
                {
                    transform.LookAt(new Vector3(player.position.x, transform.position.y, player.position.z));
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                    if (!isAttacking && distanceToPlayer <= runDistance)
                    {
                        StartCoroutine(Attack());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case EnemyState.Attacking:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        isAttacking = true;
        anim.SetBool("Running", false);
        anim.SetBool("Walking", false);
        anim.SetTrigger("Attack");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackDelay);
        isAttacking = false;
        currentState = EnemyState.Running;
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: How close is "close"? Could it be related to the transition to the "Attacking" state or does the bug occur too early or too late for that to be the case?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your player and enemy in the Scene view, with the local translation gizmo for the enemy visible? It sounds like the enemy might be oriented so that its visible "forward" differs from the direction of its local z+ (blue) axis, which is the one used for LookAt.